# Enabled checkbox by default in WordPress widgets

Tags: widgets, customization

The code works as expected.

The issue happens if I set 'show_post_count' => 1 by default. In this case checkbox will be enabled always.

How should I update the code to work as expected even if checkbox value set to 1 by default.

```
<?php

class Custom_Archives_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'custom_archives_widget', // Base ID
            __( 'Custom Archives', 'custom' ), // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'Custom Archives Widget', 'custom' ) ) // Args
        );
    }


    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        //extract( $args );
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, self::get_defaults() );

        echo $args['before_widget'];

        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ). $args['after_title'];
        }

        $instance['echo'] = false;
        $archives = wp_get_archives( $instance );

        if ( $instance['format'] == 'option' ) { // Archives as a dropdown

            echo '<p class="custom-archives"><select name="archive-dropdown" onchange=\'document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;\'>';
                echo '<option value=""></option>';
                echo $archives;
            echo '</select></p><!-- .custom-archives -->';

        } elseif ( $instance['format'] == 'html' ) { // Archives as an unordered list

            echo '<ul class="custom-archives">' . $archives . '</ul><!-- .custom-archives -->';

        } else { // Other formats

            echo $archives;

        }
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }


    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, self::get_defaults() );

        $type_list = array( 
            'yearly' => __( 'Yearly', 'custom' ),
            'monthly' => __( 'Monthly', 'custom' ),
            'daily' => __( 'Daily', 'custom' ),
            'weekly' => __( 'Weekly', 'custom' ),
            'postbypost' => __( 'Post By Post', 'custom' ),
            'alpha' => __( 'Alphabetical', 'custom' )
        );

        $format_list = array(
            'html' => __( 'HTML', 'custom' ),
            'option' => __( 'Dropdown', 'custom' ),
            'custom' => __( 'Custom', 'custom' )
        );

        $order_list = array(
            'ASC'  => __( 'Ascending (A-Z)', 'custom' ),
            'DESC' => __( 'Descending (Z-A)', 'custom' )
        );

        ?>
<p>
    <label><?php _e( 'Title:', 'custom' ); ?><br>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['title'] ); ?>">
    </label>
</p>

<p>
    <label><?php _e( 'Type:', 'custom' ); ?><br>
        <select class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'type' ); ?>">
            <?php foreach ( $type_list as $option_value => $option_label ) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $option_value ); ?>" <?php selected( $instance['type'], $option_value ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( $option_label ); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </label>
</p>

<p>
    <label><?php _e( 'Limit:', 'custom' ); ?><br>
        <input type="number" class="widefat" min="0" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'limit' ); ?>" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['limit'] ); ?>" />
    </label>
</p>

<p>
    <label><?php _e( 'Format:', 'custom' ); ?><br>
        <select class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'format' ); ?>">
            <?php foreach ( $format_list as $option_value => $option_label ) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $option_value ); ?>" <?php selected( $instance['format'], $option_value ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( $option_label ); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </label>
</p>

<p>
    <label>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $instance['show_post_count'] ); ?> 
            name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_post_count' ); ?>" />
        <?php _e( 'Show post count', 'custom' ); ?>
    </label>
</p>

<p>
    <label><?php _e( 'Order:', 'custom' ); ?><br>
        <select class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'order' ); ?>">
            <?php foreach ( $order_list as $option_value => $option_label ) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $option_value ); ?>" <?php selected( $instance['order'], $option_value ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( $option_label ); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </label>
</p>
        <?php 
    }


    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $new_instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $new_instance, self::get_defaults() );
        $instance['title'] = trim(strip_tags($new_instance['title']));
        $instance['type'] = $new_instance['type'];
        $instance['limit'] = intval( $new_instance['limit'] );
        $instance['limit'] = $instance['limit'] === 0 ? '' : $instance['limit'];
        $instance['format'] = $new_instance['format'];

        $instance['show_post_count'] = $new_instance['show_post_count'] ? 1 : 0;

        /*$instance['show_post_count'] = 1;
        if( !isset( $new_instance['show_post_count'] ) || empty( $new_instance['show_post_count'] ) ) {
            $instance['show_post_count'] = 0;
        }*/

        $instance['order'] = $new_instance['order'];
        return $instance;
    }


    /**
     * Render an array of default values.
     *
     * @return array default values
     */
    private static function get_defaults() {
        $defaults = array(
            'title' => __( 'Archives', 'custom' ),
            'description' => '',
            'type' => 'monthly',
            'limit' => 10,
            'format' => 'html',
            'show_post_count' => 0,
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );
        return $defaults;
    }

}


function custom_archives_register_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Custom_Archives_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_archives_register_widget' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please note** when checkbox is not checked then `key` is not set in posted form data.
So when you uncheck `show_post_count`, posted array does not has this key and in `update()` function you are parsing it with default value.

```
$new_instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $new_instance, self::get_defaults() );
```

Thus `$instance['show_post_count']` will have `1` always even when you uncheck it.

### Solution:

Please give the priority to user input and if something is missing then fill it with default arguments. The updated function will look like!

```
public function update( $new_instance, $instance ) {
    $instance['title'] = trim(strip_tags($new_instance['title']));
    $instance['type'] = $new_instance['type'];
    $instance['limit'] = intval( $new_instance['limit'] );
    $instance['limit'] = $instance['limit'] === 0 ? '' : $instance['limit'];
    $instance['format'] = $new_instance['format'];
    //Add isset to check if key is set!
    $instance['show_post_count'] = isset($new_instance['show_post_count']) ? 1 : 0;
    $instance['order'] = $new_instance['order'];

    //Fill with default value if any key is missing!
    $updated_instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, self::get_defaults() );

    return $updated_instance;
}
```

Comment: This solution isn't working for me. I can turn the checkbox setting on and off, but when I first activate the widget, the checkbox is shown as on in the admin menu, but the widget behaves as if it's off until I turn the setting off and on again...